# How can I rewrite a URL using PHP?

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have a URL like http://domain.com/index.php?user=test

When a user logs in, I want to show a URL like http://domain.com/user (*user* will be dynamic).

How might I achieve this with URL rewriting using PHP?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should use something based off .htaccess. Take WordPress' for instance:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This says grab any page which does not exist (such as "user" in your case), and redirect to the main `index.php` file.

That main `index.php` can then grab the "user", and you can use it to grab data from your database and show whatever you want.

---

EDIT-- similar to AlienWebguy's answer

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^like/(.+) /like.php?user=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hey Kerry,Thanks for your reply. I tried your code,but getting this error on my page when i  tried to read the user. The error is Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 1

Comment: <?php echo $_REQUEST['user'] ?>

Comment: `REQUEST` only accesses `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`, try looking for `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: Thanks ,if i want to rewirte the url  http://domain.com/like.php?user=test to  http://domain.com/like/test (here test is any username)

Comment: I mean i want this will do different when a specific word come and call the other page

Comment: when i type this http://localhost:8080/like/no, its still take me on index.php ,is this possible to   access the only like.php page in this case. Thanks for all your help

Comment: I donot know ,i didnot voted down,i'm having some problem with your code can you help me.

Comment: I donot know ,i didnot voted down,i'm having some problem with your code can you help me.how can i avoid images to be part of this

Comment: @ John -- can you give me an example URL of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look into [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in your [.htaccess](http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls)

Adding a rewrite rule in your .htaccess is simple. First, activate mod_rewrite by adding this line to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

Then add your rule to redirect your pages:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /yourpage\.php?user=$1
```